# How come when I share a link on Facebook I can only choose from 3 of my total 12 thumbnail images?

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, share, meta-tags, muse

The URL Linter detects all of my og:image thumbnails, but Facebook only allows me to choose between 3 when I share the link [(ref.)](http://oi49.tinypic.com/xd6ruh.jpg). The site is W3C verified, and I've triple checked the meta tags I'm using. The images are square jpegs that are 300x300px.

Here's the link I'm trying to share, http://proactiveresources.com/021313. The website was created using Adobe Muse, and I'm testing the share on Google Chrome.

Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question(my english is bad):
If you just created or changed your `og:` tags, you may wait 24hrs or
in order to get your Facebook thumbnails to work, you need to force Facebook to refresh its cache. If Facebook have already crawled your site/post, it stores it in its cache, and it might take 24 hours to get any new updates to show. So, that’s why you need to force Facebook to refresh its cache by adding the url to the post you want to share. 
[Visit this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

add your url then click debug
if this failed you may wait 24 hrs.

Comment: Thanks for the help Shadi. I've been debugging link with the Linter all along, but it still only pulls 3 thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to change the og:type to "website" or "product", this way Facebook will pull more images.